# Directed graphical models and independence (exercise)

Tags: self-study, graphical-model, conditional-independence

Context: this is Ex. 1 in these notes [http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=sml/DAGs.pdf](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Elarry/=sml/DAGs.pdf) .

The exercise asks to prove that, given a directed graphical model associated to a DAG (directed acyclic graph) $G$:

**Ex:** $p$ is a distribution Markov to G $\rightarrow W \mathrel{\unicode{x2AEB}} \tilde{W} | \pi_W, \forall W$

where $\tilde{W}$ indicates all variables but $W$ and its descendants, and $\pi_W$ are the parents of $W$. A distribution is called "Markov to G" if it respects:

$p(x)=\sum_{j}p(x_j|\pi_{x_j})$ [1]

, where $x$ indicates all r.v. that $G$ describes.

**My trial:**

I have to choose one way to show independence and for this I would like to use something like the small lemma reported at the end of the post, linking independence and factorization of the joint.

Now using the identifications of sets of variables:

- $A \rightarrow W$
- $B \rightarrow \tilde{W}$
- $C \rightarrow \pi_W$
- $D \rightarrow D(W)$, the descentants of $W$

,we have that $\{A,B,C,D\}$ is a partition of the entire set of variables.

Starting from [1] we would like to obtain a proper factorization of the joint. Here I face problems, because when $x_j$ in Eq. [1] is  a r.v. belonging to $D(W)$ (the descendents of W), $x_j \in D(W)$, the factor:

$p(x_j|\pi_{x_j})$

contains contributions from $D(W)$ (because we are considering $x_j$ belonging to D) but could also contain contributions from $W$ and $\tilde W$ (because both can be parents of a descendant of $W$). Therefore I find it difficult to obtain a proper factorization to solve the exercise.

Am I missing something/going in the wrong direction?

Please let me know if the question is unclear.

---

**Lemma**: given four variables (or group of variables) $A,B,C,D$ than if we can write the joint density as a product:

$p(a,b,c,d)=f_1(a,c)f_2(b,c,d)$

than:
$A \mathrel{\unicode{x2AEB}} B | C$ . Same conclusion holds if:

$p(a,b,c,d)=f_1(a,c,d)f_2(b,c)$ []